# ng-repeat in not working in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
<body ng-app="">
<div ng-init="places = [{country='Pak',conti='asia'}, {country='ind',conti='asia'}]">

  <p ng-repeat='place in places'>
    Name: {{place.name }}
    conti: {{place.counti}}
  </p>

</div>
</body>
```

The ng-repeat above is not displaying anything, I'm working using just HTML and not any specific controller or anything, just trying to display the records of array.

Comment: for the key-value pair in object you need to use colons (`:`). Change `{country='Pak',conti='asia'}` to `{country:'Pak',conti:'asia'}`, etc.

Comment: The `ng-init` directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of ngInit. See [AngularJS ng-init Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit).

Answer (score 2):

Try following

- Use valid `JSON` in `ng-init`
- Use the right keys which accessing properties like `place.country` and `place.conti`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="">
  <div ng-init="places = [{country:'Pak',conti:'asia'}, 
{country:'ind',conti:'asia'}]">
    <p ng-repeat='place in places'>
      Name: {{place.country }} conti: {{place.conti}}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use valid json object.